# Redirect directory content

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have the following directories on my Apache server:

```
root/dir1/
root/dir2/
root/dir3/...
```

Is it possible to make the contents of my sub-directories (dir1, dir2, dir3) "as if" it was directly in `root/`?

I'm looking for a solution for dynamically created directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a program or script in root that handles all requests (like a 404 `ErrorDocument`) by analyzing the URL and searching for matching files in those directories.

Since you need to think about e.g. priorities when theres `dir1/filename.ext` and `dir2/filename.ext` this is the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do some of this with RewriteRules if the directory and file names follow a pattern.